# how to read internal environment file in perl?

Tags: perl

I convert UNIX script to Perl.
In unix we have

```
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/dte.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/xfer.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/dte_reports.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/java.env
```

What should I do in Perl? The same or open and read each file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell script as a wrapper for your perl script.

```
#!/bin/sh
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/dte.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/xfer.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/dte_reports.env    
. ${DTE_WORKING_DIR}/sh/java.env
perl /path/to/file.pl
```

Inside perl script you can retrieve environment variables defined on those files.

Comment: I cannot, the system understand only Perl. I create a new Perl script, to get necessary environment

Comment: Then you must redefine variables defined on those files inside your perl script. Maybe you can open those files, parse lines to find "export" execution, an redefined on your own hash. Example: " A=B " became " $newEnv{'A'}='B' ", and you could use $newEnv{'A'}, instead of $ENV{'A'}.